# how to access the rows and able to move back and forth in spark dataframes using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to solve following problem:

input dataframe :

```
+------+------+------------+
|emp   |Group |Spouse      |
+------+------+------------+
|John  |L1    |Dana        |
|Mary  |L1    |Rick        |
|Harry |L3    |Dana        |
|Linda |L3    |Harry       |
|Jim   |L3    |Mary        |
+------+------+------------+
```

Logic: The spouse of an employee must not belong to the same group as the employee(must remove those spouse's row from the list)

output dataframe:

```
+------+------+------------+
|Emp   |Group |Spouse      |
+------+------+------------+
|John  |L1    |Dana        |
|Mary  |L1    |Rick        |
|Linda |L3    |Harry       |
|Jim   |L3    |Mary        |
+------+------+------------+
```

Would anyone please help me in resolving this?

Comment: Didn’t get it could you please explain a bit

Comment: In row-4, 'Linda' is in Group L3 and her spouse is 'Harry' is also in Group L3 (refer to row-3). Hence, the logic is to remove harry's record.

Comment: But if I look, I think I can see that Harry has 2 spouses - Linda and Dana, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left-join the dataframe into itself, based on the spouse and group columns, then filter on the non-null content in the joined DF, and drop the joined DF if not needed. Something like this:

```
df.join(df.select($"emp".as("s_e"), $"Spouse".as("s_s"), $"Group".as("s_g")),
    $"emp" <=> $"s_s" && $"Group" <=> $"s_g", "left").
  filter($"s_e".isNull).
  drop($"s_e", $"s_s", $"s_g")
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a solution for you?

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("empl")

sql("select a.emp, a.Group, a.Spouse from empl a where exists (select 1 from empl b where a.Spouse = b.emp and a.Group <> b.Group)").show
```